# I am trying to run a download data from chrome browser using chromedriver in a python file

Tags: google-chrome, selenium-chromedriver, google-image-search

I am getting this error while using chrome driver to download the google images ... the chrome driver is in path too. The executable is downloaded still the issue persists.

Windows 10 operating system .. the chromedriver is installed through pip too...

Input:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    chrome_driver = 'C:\\Users\\320086442\\AppData\\Local\\Continuum\\anaconda3\\Lib\\site-packages\\selenium\\webdriver\\chrome'

# download the emotion data
    data_dir = 'C:\\Users\\320086442\\Downloads\\emotion-master\\image_net'
    emotions = {'angry': ['angry', 'furious', 'resentful', 'irate'],
            'disgusted': ['disgusted', 'sour', 'grossed out'],
            'happy': ['happy', 'smiling', 'cheerful', 'elated', 'joyful'],
            'sad': ['sad', 'depressed', 'sorrowful', 'mournful', 'grieving', 'crying'],
            'surprised': ['surprised', 'astonished', 'shocked', 'amazed']}
    download_emotions(emotions, data_dir, chrome_driver)

# download the pseudo Imagenet data
    imagenet_labels = []
    with open('C:\\Users\\320086442\\Downloads\\emotion-master\\image_net\\imagenet_labels.txt', 'r') as file:
        for line in file:
            imagenet_labels.append(line.strip())
    data_dir = 'C:\\Users\\320086442\\Downloads\\emotion-master'
    imagenet_label_file = 'C:\\Users\\320086442\\Downloads\\emotion-master\\image_net\\imagenet_labels.txt'
    download_fake_imagenet(imagenet_labels, data_dir, chrome_driver)
```

Output:

```
 C:\Users\320086442\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\python.exe C:/Users/320086442/Downloads/emotion- 
master/download_data.py
Downloading images for: angry human face ...
Looks like we cannot locate the path the 'chromedriver' (use the '--chromedriver' argument to specify 
the path to the executable.) or google chrome browser is not installed on your machine (exception: 
use 
options instead of chrome_options)

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: Can you share the code, are you sure chrome is installed on the machine?

Comment: The code has been shared and chrome is installed on my machine